# Angular 5 (Angular 2+), Second guard does not wait for the first guard to finish http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, request

I have an application where there are two guards (AuthGuard - for logged users, AdminGuard - for admins). The AuthGuard on the first loading makes http request to get the user information from the API. The Problem is when you try to access route with both guards, the AdminGuard does not wait for the AuthGuard to finish with the request and set the user so the AdminGuard can check the role of the user, and the application breaks. I know it breaks because the user is undefined.
I'm looking for a solution on how to make the second guard to wait for the first to finish.

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminGuard]
},

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').map(res => {
            console.log('Auth Guard.');
            console.log(res);
            this.authService.user = {role: 'admin'};

            return true;
     });

         return false;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        console.log('Admin Guard.');
        console.log(this.authService.user);

        if (this.authService.user.role === 'admin') {
             return true;
        }

        return false;
   }
```

}

Here is a plnker link - http://plnkr.co/edit/EqgruNjogTJvsC1Zt5EN?p=preview

Comment: I understand auth guard is executed in the order of the array defined in route, however I dont think they will wait for one to resolve before another. I suggest putting your logic in a service and then put a switch map on your http call, since one call depend on another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very important thing to understand is that in `AuthGuard` you make an **asynchronous** call and we don't know, when it will be resolved. Other code is **synchronous** and will be executed immediately without waiting this asynchronous call (it's why the `user` is `undefined`).

But you can force `AdminGuard` to wait, while your HTTP call will be resolved: to do that, you can store **Observable Subscription** (because you're working with `observable`, but you can do the same trick with `promise` too) to `AuthService` from `AuthGuard` (where you make your HTTP call) using the following row:

```
this.authService.subscription$ = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

Now your subscription is in `AuthService`, all that you need is to `subscribe` on it in both guards (you're using `.map()` in your case):

**AuthGuard:**

```
return this.authService.subscription$.map(res => {
  this.authService.user = {role: 'admin'};
  return true;
});
```

**AdminGuard:**

```
return this.authService.subscription$.map(res => {
  if (this.authService.user.role === 'admin') {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here is the working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/R2Z26GsSvzEpPdU7tOHO?p=preview

If you see `"AuthGuard returns TRUE!"` and `"AdminGuard returns TRUE!"` in your console - everything should work fine. I have also logged `this.authService.user` variable from both `AuthGuard` and `AdminGuard`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, works perfect. Much clearer now, what's happening.

Comment: @Igor, not at all, but I strongly recommend you to remember that you can store asynchronous point and use it further, I really like it and it helps to avoid excess code writing.

Comment: I'd make one more improvement, last version of the code makes the same http request twice. Creating a Subject in the AuthService, so when we get the user in AuthGuard we forward that change was made, and we are listening for that change in the AdminGuard. Here is the plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/9UhvAuoqJMZIcfNq2Wjj?p=preview

Comment: @Igor, yes, that implementation will work too, good job! I see you know, what to do ;)

Comment: Maybe it's a correct solution for previous version of RX, but now on version 6, the http get is an observable not a subscription, plus wouldn't this solution result in an additional network request to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' since angular will subscribe to the same observable once on auth guard, then again on permissions guard ?